# PHP/MYSQL email message board logic and security

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap

I want to run this by the group to get some ideas on how to improve security.

Long story short, I have a web app that when you send an email to xxx@mydomain.com, using php and imap, the script checks the email account and then saves that email into mysql to be used for other parts of the application. We take all necessary steps to properly sanitize the data to prevent mysql injections etc.

However, In order for the incoming email to be saved into mysql, your email address has to be approved first as to not allow just anyone to have their email saved into our database.

My question is, if a hacker wanted to, they could mask the "from" email address of an approved user and if they found out our secret email address to send to, they could then have their messages saved to our database, bypassing our security measures. Is there any way to prevent this?

For instance, let's say that an approved email is safe@approved.com. Is there a way to check with PHP if that the email sent to our mail server actually came from safe@approved.com or was it masked?

I have looked at gethostbyname() , but not exactly sure how to implement it while not creating a  bunch of headaches for our legit users.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: save all emails, verified emails go into one table the rest into another and then chekc the validity. for emails in general are already existing solution to verify the reputation of mailservers look for `check mailserver reputation`

Comment: Any given email can only be verified by its mail server, not the email itself. So if you would like to know if some `email` with any given `headers` and produced `hash` was sent by `told` server. You have to verify first that `told` server is a valid email server, not blacklisted bla bla bla, then you need to ask the `told` server if some `email` was actually sent by him. There is absolutely no other way to know where the email came from. So it would be very wise that the given server you send emails with is known and validated by you.

Comment: @dbf is there a way to do that with php?

Comment: Normally your mailserver would employ this kind of spam and spoofing protection, and cut things out before they reach the inbox. Some are better at it than others. It'll never be 100% accurate though, no matter what

Comment: @ADyson @RexBanner Well it depends on what you mean by `is there a way to do that with php`, like ADyson said, the mail server does most of the work for you. When you retrieve any given email from your mail server, it adds many headers with different protocols and approaches like likelihood of spam, origin, authority, authenticity, etc. You have to filter out these headers and check against given values if an email is likely to be valid. For any other use case of "possible" mis-use, you need to build your own security measures to tackle any "possible" abuse.

Comment: @dbf - Is there information in the header that I can use to compare user history to the current email in question?

Comment: @RexBanner Well I'm kinda of the dark here. I have absolutely no user-case scenario at hand about what send the email, how it is being send, how you retrieve the email, where it is being retrieved, how you save the email, which demands have to be fulfilled before saving an email. So no, I can't really say what you need to check in the headers or other info provided by the email to verify anthing.

Comment: I am getting the responses I expected, so I guess my final question is, does anyone think my current logic that we use (approved email being sent to secret email account) is secure or not secure?

Comment: Even with SPF/DKIM (which you should already be implementing) the message contents are not secure because there is no guarantee of end-to-end encryption with SMTP. Having the clients POST to a simple authenticated HTTPS webhook would be much more secure, easier to implement, less prone to error, and significantly faster to process.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I know what an authenticated webhook is, but I am not sure i uderstand how I would use it in an email scenario like this? Would you be willing to elaborate?

Comment: If you have a webhook, there is no email scenario. The clients would hit the webhook instead of sending an email. I'm confused as to why you'd ever want to even bring email into the picture. You've already got a webapp, at the very least you could just make a form page to submit the required info.

Comment: @AlexHowansky client wants their users to be able to use their email to add to the database. I guess they want one less app to have to use, which makes sense from usability perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to verify that a `From:` header is legitimate. There are methods that can help *increase confidence* in it, though:

- [SPF records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) can be used to check that the originating server is authorized to send for that domain, though this won't help with the "local-part", or the individual sending.
- [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) signing can indicate that the actual address used is authorized by that server, something often included by default on most email platforms (e.g. Gmail).

Unless you do additional work to verify these headers you've got no way of knowing.

If you're expecting email from an unsigned source, with no SPF records, it's anyone's guess as to if that's legitimate or not.

This is why you'll often see services with a "mail in" end point use obfuscated delivery addresses, that is a secret address of sorts that can be used to communicate with the app or service. For example, [Evernote](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050995914) uses this approach, giving a unique destination email for each user.

This provides at least a layer of security in that unless that address is leaked out, it's highly unlikely that some attacker could exploit that address. Anything sent there is probably from the authorized individual.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by additional work?

Comment: As in validate on an SPF and/or DKIM level by reading the headers and performing the required tests. Some mail servers will do this automatically, so it may not be necessary, but if you're receiving a raw stream of email, unfiltered, you'll have to do this.